# xcode binary file checkout and push to git hub causes issues

Tags: xcode, git

Add, commit to a local branch repository,

```
git add *.*
git commit -m "msg"
```

I push code to remote branch

```
git push branch
```

I get the same error on a Xcode specific file

```
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    modified:   abc/abc.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/axz.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate
```

I have to add and commit that file again and then push works

Next I merge my branch into main

```
git checkout main
git merge branch
```

I get same error on the same file
Changes not staged for commit:
(use "git add ..." to update what will be committed)
(use "git restore ..." to discard changes in working directory)
modified:   abc/abc.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/axz.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate

I have to add and commit the file and then push

```
git push
```

Then it works.
I don't know why this specific file does not get included in the initial add/commit/push and I have to perform add/commit/push separately on this specific file.

This file UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate is specific to user I assume. As I work in team,  so will I be overwriting someone else's UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate file? Can someone explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`xcuserdata` should be ignored from source control, you can add it to your `.gitignore`.

> xcuserdata/

Comment: Thank you. What about this file, where I am having the same issue: abc/abc.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/axz.xcuserdatad/xcdebugger/Breakpoints_v2.xcbkptlist Should this file be added to  .gitignore too?

Comment: No, that can be ignored too, the slash of the end of the xcuserdata/ means, that the whole folder can be ignored.

Comment: saves me lot of headache